# What conversions does the conversion constructor do if an object is created and assigned a value?

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit

If I have a class with a constructor like this:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int e) {
      // Use the `e` value
    }
};
```

And if I make calls like this:

```
int main() {
  A obj = 'c';
}
```

What conversions would take place? Would a conversion to type `A` take place first, then how is it passed onto the constructor? Or would the character value be converted to `int`?

Also which conversions here is blocked by declaring the constructor explicit?

---

To clarify my doubts:

If I declare the constructor as `explicit`, I see these results:

```
int main() {
  A objA = 'x';   // Error: conversion from ‘char’ to non-scalar type ‘A’ requested
  A objA('x');    // OK
  A objA = 1;     // Error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘A’ requested

  A objA = A(1);  // OK: Constructor called explicitly
  A objA = (A)1;  // OK: type Casting
}
```

I don't understand the behavior in the former three statements. Why do the first and third statements have conversion to `A` type and not to `int` in the first?
Why does the second statement compile even though there is an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`?

Comment: A constructor would be called with 'c' (`char`) casted to `int`. Declaring it as explicit would generate a compile time error.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, if i declare constuctor as explicit, the compile time error i get is `conversion from ‘char’ to non-scalar type ‘A’ requested` but only if `'c'` is assigned, not if i pass it like `A obj('c')`, then it compiles.

Comment: This is not an assignment, it's an initialisation. Both use the `=` symbol, but they are very different.

Comment: Related: [What does the explicit keyword mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/121162)

Comment: The error messages are a bit misleading  (they originate from older versions of C++ where `A objA = 'x';` was defined as creating a temporary as if by `A('x')` and then initialize `objA` from the temporary) .  It would be better if the message said something like "copy-initialization selected an explicit constructor"

Comment: @M.M According to (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit), explicit constructor cannot be used for implicit conversions, but `A objA('x');` gives no errors, is the conversion of `'x'` (`char`) to `int` is not what they are referring to?

Comment: @amithm7 `char` to `int` does not require any constructor

Comment: @M.M when is it that an implicit conversion requires a constructor? Are they referring to the conversion to `A` type from another type?

Comment: Conversion of `char` to class type requires a constructor.  `A a('x')` is considered explicit conversion, and `A a = 'x';` is considered implicit conversion

Answer (score 1):

```
A obj = 'c';
A obj = 1;
```

These are called *copy-initialization*. Only converting constructors (i.e., non-explicit constructors) that accept one argument is considered in this case, with the only one being

```
A(int e)
{
  // ...
}
```

`'c'` (`char`) is converted to `int` and then given to the selected constructor as argument.

If you declare the constructor as `explicit`, then it is not a converting constructor, and *copy-initialization* fails to find a suitable converting constructor, making the program ill-formed.

---

```
A obj('c');
A obj{'c'}; // since C++11
A obj(1);

A(1);
(A)1;
```

These are called *direct-initialization*. All constructors (including explicit ones) are considered in this case. Therefore, regardless of whether you declare the constructor as explicit or not, the constructor is called.

Comment: For explicit constructors, in case of copy-initialization, i get errors like `conversion from ‘char’ to non-scalar type ‘A’ requested`. Why is that if the conversion only happens from `char` to `int`?

Comment: @amithm7 Because `char` cannot be converted to `A`. It can only be converted to `int`, and `int` cannot be converted further.

Comment: i only get that error when constructor is explicit. So `char` can be converted to `A` when constructor is non-explicit?

Comment: @amithm7 Yes. If `A::A(int)` is not explicit, then `char` can be first converted to `int` and then converted further to `A`.